# jQuery FullCalendar doesn't show events issue in FireFox 33.0

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, firefox, fullcalendar

I'm trying to set up jQuery FullCalendar by providing data as json feed trough fullcalendar **events** function. So basically this is my js code:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  editable: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  header: {
    left: 'prev, next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
  },

  events: 
  {
    url: 'events.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    error: function() {
      alert('ERROR');
    },
    color: 'blue'
  }
});
```

And my code from events.php which pulls data from database and makes as JSON feed + converting date to ISO8601 date strings as sayd in documentation.

```
// Query that retrieves events
$q = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER by id";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) 
{
    $s = new DateTime($row['start']);
    $e = new DateTime($row['end']);
    $row['start'] = $s->format(DATE_ISO8601);
    $row['end']   = $e->format(DATE_ISO8601);
    $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

In IE11 and Chrome it shows all the events in calendar what are made in DB, but in FireFox the calendar is empty.. And returned response JSON string is:

```
[
{"id":"7","title":"Rino","start":"2014-10-22T11:55:46+0300","end":"2014-10-22T11:55:46+0300","url":"nav","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"8","title":"Rin","start":"2014-10-22T13:01:45+0300","end":"2014-10-22T13:01:45+0300","url":"Hello","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"9","title":"Rino","start":"2014-10-23T10:06:22+0300","end":"2014-10-23T10:06:22+0300","url":"Hello","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"10","title":"a","start":"2014-10-23T09:42:04+0300","end":"2014-10-23T09:42:04+0300","url":"a","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"11","title":"1","start":"2014-10-23T09:41:55+0300","end":"2014-10-23T09:41:55+0300","url":"1","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"12","title":"sdas","start":"2014-10-23T10:06:14+0300","end":"2014-10-23T10:06:14+0300","url":"1","allDay":"false"},
{"id":"13","title":"Prju","start":"2014-10-16T00:00:00+0300","end":"2014-10-17T00:00:00+0300","url":"undefined","allDay":"false"}
]
```

What am I missing, why in the Firefox it doesn't show any event? I have also tried clearing cache etc.. but without any results..

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, even if you set data locally?

Comment: I just noticed an interesting thing. That events disappear from page after I open firebug and do something in that current page. Afterwards content has been disappeared. After reopening browser content is back. By disabling firebug everything is again ok...

Comment: I did't noticed anything strange, even with firebug open, here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kxsncLL/)

Comment: Yeah I've tried in fiddle too and it works good. And also it works fine even in FireFox if I write manually JSON string in events like it's done in fiddle. But if I'm getting that JSON string from different page as I'm trying to do then there is this firebug glitch.